# How to migrate WordPress website from localhost to live server?

Tags: wordpress

I have developed a website in WordPress in my localhost. Now I am trying to transfer it in live server exactly as it was in my localhost.

I tried it myself and found many changes after uploading on live server.

I have found solution of it but nothing is working perfectly.

**UPDATE:** The problem was my ability to search and find proper documentation. Long story short- there are 4/5 simple & easy ways of transferring WordPress website from localhost to livehost OR one location to another. Below I mentioned my most preferred way of transferring WordPress websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can transfer WordPress websites from one location to another OR localhost to livehost using few different ways. We can create database on livehost using phpMyAdmin and transfer all the files and folders; but this approach takes huge time & effort. Based on my personal perception, here is the **best & quickest solution ever:**

**All-in-One WP Migration** Plugin.

**1st Step:** Login to your Localhost or the website you want to migrate from. Install & activate the All-in-One WP Migration plugin. Once you activate the plugin, navigate to **"All-in-One WP Migration" => "Export"** and click on the dropdown **"EXPORT TO"** & choose the option called **"File"**. Finally download & save the exported file into your device.

**2nd & Final Step:** Now login to your **another** WordPress website you want the website **migrate to.** If you already have not installed WordPress CMS on the new location/website then you have to install WordPress first before moving forward. Once you installed WordPress on the new location/website, go ahead and install & activate the same plugin called **All-in-One WP Migration**. Once you install & activated the plugin, navigate to **"All-in-One WP Migration" => "Import"** and drag & drop previously taken/saved exported file here. Be patient, it will take some time to be uploaded. Click **"Proceed"** once it done with Unpacking the Archive. Once the process is completed, **login again** to the website using the **old website username & password**. On the WordPress Dashboard navigate to **"Settings" => "Permalinks"** and select the option called **"Post name"** and hit the **"Save Changes"** button **twice**.

Congratulation! You're almost done.

[image]
**All-in-One WP Migration** Plugin [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/)

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question, and it's asked a lot. In fact it's asked so much that if you were to simple Google 'Transfer Wordpress to live site', you would have found your answer very easily. This is the first hit: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/

But in a nutshell, there are a few steps you need to do to transfer.

1. Sounds obvious, but firstly I would set up your hosting account, and your FTP access. At this stage, also create a new database.
2. Go to the database manager of your localhost, and export the entire database for your Wordpress site to an SQL file, keep it somewhere you'll find it, like the Desktop.
3. Import that database file into your live site control panel (if they have restrictions on the file size you can upload, then you can re-export from your local site as compressed, or ZIP, and try uploading again). While you're here, open the wp_options table and update the siteurl and home settings to match your live domain.
4. Copy all of your local site files from the root directory into your FTP account.
5. Open your wp-config.php file and update your database settings to match those for your live site.

Open a browser and navigate to your live site domain, and you should see your website just as you left it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this work in this 2 ways :

1- You can download & install [Duplicator WordPress Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins-wp/duplicator/) and do that easily only by one click and then transfer to your live server and install that!

2- You can copy & paste all of your folders in your localhost to your live server & then export your localhost database & import that to your live server database , then use your site!

i prefere do this wok with my first way.
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

How to Upload Wordpress Website Localhost to Live Server Using C Panel

upload wordpress website localhost to FTP or C panel

Step 1 : create ZIP file of your website which in htdocs(localhost)

Step 2 : Upload ZIP file on public.html (FTP/cpanel)

Step 3 : Extract your zip folder under public.html

Step 4 : Move all files of your website on public.html
open folder > select all file > click on move > choose path /public.html> move

Step 5 : Create database > go back to your cpanel > find out MySQL Database Wizard

Step 6 : click on MySQL database wizard then create a database

```
 a : Create A Database > database_name (save your database name on notepad)
 
 b : Create Username & password of your database

 c : Click on Create User

 d : Add user to the database > select all > click next > your database create successfully
```

Step 7 : Go back cpanel and click on phpMyAdmin under databases

Step 8 : Now open your localhost database "localhost/phpmyadmin"

Step 9 : Now Export your local database (download your local database)

step 10 : Now some changes in the download sql file. open your download sql file in any editor(html or text editor)

Step 11 : replace http://localhost/website_name to your website url ([www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)) and save

Step 12 : now follow step 7 and open your database then Import your sql file in your database

Step 13 : Go back your public.html folder and open "wp-config.php" file and edit your database name, username & password then save file

Step 14 : Now check your website Url on browser, your website uploaded on server

Step 15 : Sometimes internal files not open when upload local data to server for this issue you can follow below step

```
 a : Open your wordpress admin(login wordpress) "www.domain.com/wp-admin" (you login wordpress with your localhost wordpress id & password)

 b : wordpress dashboard > setting > permalinks > firstly select plain then save and refresh your website url in browser and check all links of your website
 
 c : Now again select Post name & save
```

Step 16 : Now your wordpress website is uploaded on the server & you can work on your pages , post , blogs , product etc.